# How to log / echo a string to the Result pane in the AppleScript Script Editor?

Tags: macos, applescript

How do I log a string to the *Result* pane in the Script Editor window with AppleScript?  I tried this but it shows nothing:

```
log "my log message"
```

Comment: The Result pane just shows the value returned by the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **View** > **Show Log    ⌘3**

The log message will be displayed in the **Messages**, **Events**, and **Replies** panes.

[image]